# How to replace numbers with their negative on every second line?

Tags: perl, awk, sed

I have huge files containing numbers, say

```
1.5 1.6 1.7
-5
2.1 2.8 -.3
4.005
```

and would like to change them to

```
-1.5 -1.6 -1.7
-5
-2.1 -2.8 .3
4.005
```

i.e. replace all numbers by their negative values on every second line. By that I mean all odd line numbers.

Does anyone know how to do that? Combining answers to related questions did not work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest this, which works by adding or removing the minus sign at the start of each number. Anything that is not a number is left untouched

```
perl -pe's/(?<!\S)(-?)([\d.]+)/$1 ? $2 : "-$2" /ge if $. % 2' myfile.txt
```

#### output

```
-1.5 -1.6 -1.7
-5
-2.1 -2.8 .3
4.005
```

Comment: This would be great if it didn't change the exponent sign in scientific notation.

Comment: This is the best answer because of full preservation of format and text. Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

Perl to the rescue:

```
perl -lane '$. % 2 and $_ = -$_ for @F; print "@F"' input > output
```

- `-n` reads the input line by line
- `-a` splits each line into the @F array
- `-l` adds newlines to print
- `$.` contains the line number, `%` is the modulo operator. `$. % 2` is true for each odd line.

Comment: Wow. Fast and perfectly working answer... thanks a lot!!

Comment: This will mangle the format of your file and replace any whitespace with a single space.

Comment: @TLP: True. You can split manually by `split /(\s+)/` and use the same modulo trick to only change the odd elements in the array.

Comment: I am checking out a regex substitution variant, but it keeps putting in `+` for negated values, which is passing odd.

Comment: @TLP: the whitespace issue is fine with me. pluses and the newly created 0 in front of .3 are ok, too, for my purpose.

Answer (score 4):

With awk:

```
$ awk 'NR % 2 {for (i=1;i<=NF;++i) $i=-$i}1' oddneg.txt 
-1.5 -1.6 -1.7
-5
-2.1 -2.8 0.3
4.005
```

**NR % 2**
Perform this action only when the current line number mod 2 is not zero (i.e., do this for odd lines).

**{for (i=1;i<=NF;++i) $i = -$i}**
Loop through the columns setting each to its negative

**1**
Print the current (modified) line. (awk idiom that works because `1` evaluates to true, and the default action is to print the current line.)

Comment: you can also write `$1=-$1` avoiding multiplication, not that it matters much.

Comment: I agree @karakfa, no reason to multiply. Updated.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '1~2{s/\S\+/-&/g;s/--//g}' file
```

Assuming the only values in the file are numbers. Insert a negative sign infront of each number. If there are two consecutive negative signs the original number was negative so remove the sign.

Comment: This is perfect for purely numerical content. Tank you.